# FluentValidation testing validating input is of type decimal

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

In the code base there is a model where density factor is assigned like so:

```
public decimal DensityFactor { get; set; }
```

What I am now trying to do with fluent validation is create a rule for validating that what is inputted by a user is in fact of type decimal. The input type is set to number on the html side but this is just a precaution incase they change it to text in developer tools, there is also frontend validation for making sure it's a number but again, the backend validation is a precaution incase the frontend one fails for whatever reason

I have tried to create a rule like so:

```
RuleFor(material => material.DensityFactor)
                            .Must(m => decimal.TryParse(m.ToString(), out var val))
                            .WithMessage("df must be a number");
```

However it seems like this just doesn't get hit at all so I know I must have gone wrong somewhere in setting this up. Where the issue is though, I'm not too sure.

Really want I'm wanting to do is to have a check so that if someone manages to input something like "Density Factor" instead of putting in 1 or 2 or whatever, this validation will kick and return with that error

Comment: Why convert it to a string and back? It should already be a number if it’s of type decimal

Comment: If it's of type `decimal` in your dto, it will fail to deserialize if it doesn't fit the requirements needed to be parsed into `decimal`. So this validation is completely superfluent.

Comment: Like I said in the post it's just there as a precaution and so the user can get a meaningful message back rather than just "internal server error" or something along that lines

Comment: If it's not a number that's entered (if the UI allowed for that) it wouldn't even get to that validation. It would fail _before_.

Comment: @Fildor so is there anyway around that? It is set as a decimal in the dto, which is where the error I do get is coming from I assume but have been asked to do a custom error instead which is why I'm trying to do something like I am

Comment: Either the person doesn't know better or tried to mock you. That's like checking whether an `int` var holds a value that's greater than int.MaxValue. It cannot. Check is completely senseless.

Comment: **IF** it was a `double` then you _could_ check for `Infinity` or `NaN`, though.

Comment: I don't think this was mocking at all. This was just so we could return a custom message from the server rather than something like, "cannot convert string to a decimal". But thanks, think I'll double check what they want to do

Comment: In that case, you might need an ExceptionHandling middleware to turn parsing errors into "readable" messages.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice @Fildor. I'll look into doing that. Appreciate the explanation

Comment: You are welcome. In their domain, it _may_ make sense. Like JavaScript where you have nothing that would stop you from assigning bull to a var that is _supposed_ to hold a floating point number...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's valid for your case, but I used to test it like this:

```
RuleFor(material => material.DensityFactor)
                        .Must(m => m.ToString().IsNumeric())
                        .WithMessage("df must be a number");
```

Extension method code:

```
public static bool IsNumeric(this string value)
{
    return value.All(char.IsNumber);
}
```

Regex Solution:

```
public static bool IsNumeric(this string value)
{
    var r = new Regex(@"^\d+\.?\d*$");
    return r.IsMatch(value);
}
```

Works for me. I hope it helps.

Comment: How would this work? Would you not get an error saying that string doesn't contain a definition for IsNumeric?
Also as was pointed out, it doesn't even reach this stage due to it being set as a decimal on the dto so it fails before it reaches this point

Comment: Did you implement the Extension Method and run the test? You said you already knew it was extra validation, I thought you'd just like a way to validate decinal or numeric...

Comment: Did try creating the extension method, but when calling it like you have, it says string doesn't contain a definition for isNumeric

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/C5wlM5